# Ignoring letters when parsing a double from a line in a file

Tags: java, parsing, double

I am trying to import some data from a file line by line. One specific line I was to read from may or may not have "kB" (kiloBytes) at the end and I want to parse the double that is in this line but my program gives me java.lang.NumberFormatException.

```
    while(inputStream.hasNextLine())
    {
        inputStream.nextLine(); // Skips a line between each object
        String sn = inputStream.nextLine();
        String sa = inputStream.nextLine();
        double ss = Double.parseDouble(inputStream.nextLine()); // This is where the problem occurs
        int sd    = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine());
        addSong(sn, sa, ss, sd); // Send the four variables for Song() to the addSong method
    }
    inputStream.close();
```

I have a feeling I could work with indexOf() here but I'm not sure how.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't be afraid to have descriptive identifier names in your code. A name like `sn` is vague but something like `songName` would be much clearer.

Comment: Thanks David, I am using more descriptive terms in my Song class but this i just used to pass the parameters. It's a very small program but you are right I should probably use more descriptive names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just strip out all non-digits/dots from the line as you read it, by applying `replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")`:

```
double ss = Double.parseDouble(inputStream.nextLine().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
```

This keeps it to one line.

Comment: No worries. Not to be sour grapes at not being picked as the accepted answer, but I will point out that if you get *any* other character than a letter, even including a space, you will get the same error with the accepted answer that you're currently getting. My code however will protect you from all wayward characters that may be present. Cheers m8

Comment: One of the 2 answers with replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "") should be the accepted answer, replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "") is not as good a solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
double ss = Double.parseDouble(inputStream.nextLine().replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", ""));
```

This will help you remove all characters from A-Z regardless of cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove "kB", you can try the following :

```
String line = inputStream.nextLine();
line = line.replaceFirst("kB", "");
double ss = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

If you want to remove everything that can't be parsed by `parseDouble`, you have to use a regexp :

```
String line = inputStream.nextLine();
line = line.replaceAll("[^-\\d.]", "");
double ss = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

This regexp remove everything that is not :

- a digit (you may want to use `0-9` instead of `\\d` if you are not interested in matching UTF-8 numbers)
- or a dot (used for the decimal part)
- or a minus sign (used for negative numbers).

Comment: Thanks, Florent. I didn't know about the replaceAll() :)